# Issues when compiling the solution file for vtk using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake, vtk

Like I said, I'm trying to compile VTK (version 5.10.1) using CMake (2.8.12) and QT (4.7.4)

After following the instructions for installing QT using visual studios cmd line, I open up vtk's source, run CMAKE, and attempt to compile the solution file using Visual Studio Pro.

There's a few libraries that aren't compiling, but I'm hoping if someone can explain how to fix one, I can try and fix the others on my own.

When building QVTKWidgetPlugin, I keep getting the following error codes:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/10/2015 9:57:50 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Win32\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Win32\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Win32\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10
2>------ Build started: Project: QVTKWidgetPlugin, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>Build started 8/10/2015 9:57:51 PM.
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Touching "QVTKWidgetPlugin.dir\Release\QVTKWidgetPlugin.unsuccessfulbuild".
2>CustomBuild:
2>  All outputs are up-to-date.
2>ClCompile:
2>  All outputs are up-to-date.
2>Link:
2>     Creating library C:/vtk/bin/bin/Release/QVTKWidgetPlugin.lib and object C:/vtk/bin/bin/Release/QVTKWidgetPlugin.exp
2>Q4VTKWidgetPlugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct QString::Data QString::shared_null" (?shared_null@QString@@0UData@1@A) referenced in function "public: __thiscall QString::QString(void)" (??0QString@@QAE@XZ)
2>Q4VTKWidgetPlugin.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QListData::Data QListData::shared_null" (?shared_null@QListData@@2UData@1@A) referenced in function "public: __thiscall QList<class QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface *>::QList<class QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface *>(void)" (??0?$QList@PAVQDesignerCustomWidgetInterface@@@@QAE@XZ)
2>moc_Q4VTKWidgetPlugin.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QWidget::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QWidget@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
2>moc_Q4VTKWidgetPlugin.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QObject::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QObject@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
2>C:\vtk\bin\bin\Release\QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
2>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I understand that its basically looking for things that aren't defined, but I'm not sure how to fix it. As far as I know this should all run 100% from QT->VTK but I'm having some issues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check if the variables qt_support and qt_path correctly are correctly configured when running cmake for vtk?

Comment: I have neither of those listed by default in my CMake. Should those be added?

Comment: You should find them in the advanced view of cmake. Sorry, it is qtdir. For the correct configuration see http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/QtSetup , http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build#Configure_with_Qt

Comment: can you copy de cmake cache to the question ?